# Binding Hashed Password to SQL Prepared Statement

Tags: php, prepared-statement, sha256, varbinary

I am having trouble pulling back data from my DB when using a hashed password. I use hash_hmac/sha256 as follows:

```
function get_password_hash($password){
return hash_hmac('sha256',$password,'xxxxxxx',false);
}
```

`$p` is a non-hashed password; with this stored in my database, the below works perfectly:

```
$loginQuery = $dbc->prepare("SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE (email=? AND pass=?)");
$loginQuery->bind_param('ss',$e,$p);
$loginQuery->execute();
$loginQuery->bind_result($id,$username);

while($loginQuery->fetch()){
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}
```

If i update my database to hold the hashed password instead, and update the above to be as follows, the SQL statement brings nothing back from my database.

```
$pas = get_password_hash($p);
$loginQuery = $dbc->prepare("SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE (email=? AND pass=?)");
$loginQuery->bind_param('ss',$e,$pas);
$loginQuery->execute();
$loginQuery->bind_result($id,$username);

while($loginQuery->fetch()){
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}
```

I understand that this is because the database record holds the hashed password in a varbinary field but in my SQL query, I am using a string.

The parameter type options i can use in the prepared statement are String, Blob, Double and Integer; which of these relate to varbinary fields in my DB?

I saw a similar post which suggested a fix using `pack()` to convert string to binary; how would this work here?

Comment: For one, don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string` *and* parameter binding. It's either or, never both.

Comment: Secondly, output your `$pas` variable to confirm it's the same value as the hash in your database.

Comment: You should probably use `false` in your hmac to get a string result, and just use that instead of the binary encoding (which will indeed break when you use both `mysqli_real_escape_string` and parameter binding)

Comment: I removed any mysqli_real_escape_string, used false in my hmac and tested db hash versus $pas using the below. Still nothing returned from database.

Comment: $passwordHashQ = "SELECT pass FROM `users` WHERE username = 'Test'";
$passHash = mysqli_query($dbc,$passwordHashQ);
$pas = get_password_hash($p);
if($passHash=$pas){echo 'Y';}else{echo 'N';}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747894/php-inserting-binary-data-in-mysql-using-prepared-statements

Comment: Above is the question that looks similar but it is unclear how to make pack() work in my circumstance. I am getting Type H: illegal hex digit errors when trying $binPas = pack("H*", $pas);

Comment: Why are you insisting on storing the password in a VARBINARY field? When you call `hash_hmac()` with the fourth parameter set to `false` like you have it returns a regular string, not a binary string.

Comment: If you want a *binary* string just set that parameter to `true` and don't bother with `pack()` at all.

Comment: Im not insisting anything; I setup everything following instructions from a textbook (obviously outdated as it didnt use prepared statements). I changed false per the suggestion above. Would I be better using a true parameter in my hmac and varbinarym (if so, why isnt the above prepared statement working?), or false hmac param and a varchar field in my DB?