# create file from php unpacking file_get_contents

Tags: php, image, pdf, hex, unpack

```
<?php

// // $bin = pack("S", 65535);
// // $ray = unpack("S", $bin);
// $ray = pack("H*hex", $data);
// print_r($ray);die();
// echo "UNSIGNED SHORT VAL = ", $ray[1], "\n";


$file = file_get_contents("C:\\Users\\qwerty\Downloads\\image001.jpg", true);
// $file = file_get_contents("C:\\Users\\qwerty\\Downloads\\request.pdf", true);
$data = '0x'.unpack('H*hex', $file)['hex'];

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
// header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="request.pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image001.jpg');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Content-Length: 80685');
echo $data;
?>
```

I want am trying to create File from unpacking the same file. I am recreating this from my other function that unpacks a file stores the data in database and recreate the file again using the data. The above is my sample demo for the bigger function. What it does is unpack file content then echo again. Problem is the downloaded file (image or pdf) cant be opened. Any idea is appreciated

> I think I saw the problem when I opened the file in notepad it has a newline before the image data how can I make sure there will be no new line in before the data?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `unpack()`? Why not just echo `$file`? Databases store in binary format. There shouldn't be a need to involve another method pack/unpack, etc...

Comment: Im storing the data in database. This is just a simple demo for the project im working on @FrankerZ

Comment: You should use blob columns or store file names in db. If you use packing try `var_dump(pack('H*',(unpack("H*hex", $data))['hex']));`

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone i have varbinary as column type in database. Let me try this suggestion of yours

Comment: The previous example should just output `$data` (unpacked, i.e. transformed to hex, and packed back to binary). However, I would store the file as is with a prepared statement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747894/php-inserting-binary-data-in-mysql-using-prepared-statements

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone my problem is downloading the base64 string as image. when downloading as pdf it is ok but for image it is showing that it is not supported

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I think I saw the problem when I opened the file in notepad it has a newline before the image data how can I make sure there will be no new line in before the data?

Comment: With `ltrim()` for example. -- Please don't use comments for personal support requests. Update your question with new information or refined details. It's vastly useless to future visitors to have a question asking about arbitrary escaping, but not showcase one single reproducible sample.

Comment: @mario updated the OP now